# Can I install Windows 7 from ISO then activate with key from DVD

Tags: windows-7, dvd, iso-image, windows-activation, product-key

If I download a legit windows 7 iso from here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-recovery and I have a legit windows 7 installation DVD (retail, not OEM), can I activate using that product key?

Comment: It looks like it will verify your product key on that page anyway, so that should answer your question. If the key is valid, then yes.

Comment: @MC10 Thought so, can't check because I haven't bought the key yet, wanted to check before buying

Comment: That download is only for retail purchased Windows 7, will not work with OEM keys, so yes it should work if your key is truly a legit retail key that has never been activated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your windows 7 DVD is just a ISO burned on a DVD, so it's completely the same.